# Input string was not in a correct format. Date.ToShortTimeString

Tags: vb.net

hi can anyone help me in this code? my error is ("input string was not in a correct format")

my lblmonin.text have ("hh:mm:ss") format
and lblmonout.text ("hh:mm:ss") format

Dim TimeA As Date
Dim TimeB As Date
Dim hh As Integer
Dim mm As Integer
Dim ss As Integer

```
    'Calculation for Monday
    If Not Date.TryParse(lblmonin.Text, TimeA) Then
    End If
    If Not Date.TryParse(lblmonout.Text, TimeB) Then
    End If
    hh = TimeB.Subtract(TimeA).Hours
    mm = TimeB.Subtract(TimeA).Minutes
    ss = TimeB.Subtract(TimeA).Seconds

    Dim span As New TimeSpan
    span = TimeSpan.Parse(TimeB.ToShortTimeString) - TimeSpan.Parse(TimeA.ToShortTimeString)
    lblmontotal.Text = span.ToString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TimeSpan.Parse` throws a `FormatException` because it doesn't accept the format of the string returned by `DateTime.ToShortTimeString` (which includes the AM/PM indicator).

Just subtract the two dates:

```
span = TimeB - TimeA
```

Comment: hmmm what if i format my time to shorttimestring will it return the same error or not?